# Unicode character escaping with JavaScriptSerializer on ASP.NET MVC depends on configuration?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, json, unicode

When serializing a JSON string with

`JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize(model)`

some Unicode characters like U+2028(LINE SEPARATOR) get escaped on one environment and on another not.

The problem is that locally when developing, this character is being escaped to \u2028 in the JSON string returned by that serializing function, but on another environment this character doesn't get escaped breaking the JavaScript. The browser finds this character really rendered which is a line terminator for JavaScript, and is [illegal](http://timelessrepo.com/json-isnt-a-javascript-subset):

Chrome console error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

The server usees IIS 7.5 with ASP.NET MVC 4 and the exact same data is serialized.

What could be affecting the way this JavaScriptSerializer deals with those characters? The
.NET version on both environments is 4.0.30319.

Comment: It looks like it should be fixed in .NET 4.5.1 judging by the current [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/xsp/system/Web/Util/HttpEncoder.cs#db8b7fff506d25f0). This definitely didn't used to be the case, but I don't know which version it was that fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that on the development environment there was an update of the .NET FW 4 installed, which was not installed on the server. I couldn't find out exactly with what patch of the framework this issue got fixed. At least version 4.0.30319 like posted, seems to still have this issue.

.NET 4.5.1 as you can check in the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/xsp/system/Web/Util/HttpEncoder.cs#db8b7fff506d25f0) has this fixed.

The solution we found was to migrate to Newtonsoft JSON and use that serializer.